# Include Specific Content For Some Pages

Tags: java, tapestry

I have a layout.tml, where I defined common things I wish for my each page to have. However, now I have a problem, when I want to include specific content (marketing for example) for some page. I guess this is wrong idea, but inside my layout.tml I created marketingBlock. I want this, to be hidden until I call it somewhere, like in case page2.tml, where I want that page to include this block. Problem is, it does not show up.

So how do I do this?

```
<t:block id="marketingBlock">
    <div class="row marketing">
       <h4>Marketing Name</h4>
       <img />
        <p></p>
    </div>
</t:block>
```

***Layout.tml***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd" >
    <head>
        <title>${title}</title>
        ...
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <nav>
                    ...
                </nav>
                <h3 class="text-muted">Site Name</h3>
            </div>

            <t:body />

            <!-- i want this portion to be included for some specific pages only -->
            <t:block id="marketingBlock">
                <div class="row marketing">
                    <h4>Marketing Name</h4>
                    <img />
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </t:block>

            <footer class="footer">
                <p>&copy; Company 2015</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>  
</html>
```

***Page2.tml***

```
<html t:type="layout" title="TapestryTest Index"
      t:sidebarTitle="Framework Version"
      xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd"
      xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">

      <body>
            <div class="content">
                ...
            </div>

      <t:block id="marketingBlock" />

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it the other way around. Your Layout class is a component, and like any Tapestry component it can have parameters, and a parameter can be a block of HTML from the parent page. So if you want each page to provide different marketing content to the Layout component, the approach that you want is to pass a block from from the containing page to the Layout component via the Layout component's "marketing" parameter.

See the example at the bottom of http://tapestry.apache.org/layout-component.html -- in that example a block of CSS is being passed into the Layout component, but it could just as easily be a block of HTML.

So your Page2.tml would look like this:

```
<html t:type="layout" title="TapestryTest Index"
      xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd"
      xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">
<p:marketing>
    <div class="row marketing">
        <h4>Marketing Name</h4>
        <img />
        <p></p>
    </div>
</p:marketing>
<body>
    <div class="content">
                ...
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively, if you want multiple pages to have the *same* marketing content but allow some pages to have no marketing content at all, then you should put the marketing div inside your Layout template (as in your example), and have each parent page just pass in a boolean parameter ("showMarketing") that controls whether that div should appear. Then you can just put a  component in your Layout that tests that boolean.

So your Layout template would have this:

```
<t:if test="showMarketing">
    <div class="row marketing">
        <h4>Marketing Name</h4>
        <img />
        <p></p>
    </div>
</t:if>
```

and each page would have a "showMarketing" parameter like this at the top, set to either "true" or "false":

```
<html t:type="layout" showMarketing="true" title="TapestryTest Index"
  xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd"
  xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">
```

Comment: Thanks on your reply. However, what's the point of writing two times `<div class="row marketing">
        <h4>Marketing Name</h4>
        <img />
        <p></p>
    </div>` Is it possible to make a component (or however you call it) inside layout.tml, with this content, and then call it on another page, in one line?

Comment: I suggested 2 alternatives. You would choose one suggestion or the other, not both. If you have more than one page that needs the same marketing content, use the second suggestion, which is to have the marketing content in the Layout template and have the Layout component have a boolean parameter that each page can set to true or false. I'll edit my answer to be a little clearer.

Comment: Without seeing your code it's hard to be certain, but the error message is pretty accurate: probably your Layout class is missing the showMarketing property (there is no getter/setter, and the field isn't annotated with @Propery). You might want to look at the Component Parameters page of the Tapestry docs if you aren't familiar with component parameters.

Comment: Which class code would you like to see ? About `@Property` annotaion, do I have to create showMarketing (of what type - Object ? ) in Layout class with `@Propery` notaion on it?

Comment: Yes, if you haven't already done so, add a Boolean showMarketing field in the Layout class, with both Parameter and Property annotations.